# Mojave requires OS reinstall on restart or power on. MACH Reboot type 14 = page fault. Screenshot

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, ssd, mojave, apfs

**SPECS:**

- **Computer**: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) MacBookPro11,3.
- **Memory**: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- **HD**: 1 TB APPLE SSD SM1024F Apple_APFS
- **GRAPHICS**: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

Everytime I restart my computer or power it on my computer won't boot. I have to enter recovery mode and reinstall Mojave. I've run disk utility but no problems are detected.

Sceenshot of verbose mode:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is how I fixed my problem. As noted in a comment the issue looks to be caused by a system extension. Here's what I did to fix it.

1. I ran this command in my terminal: `system_profiler SPExtensionsDataType > ~/Desktop/kextList.txt`
2. I opened `~/Desktop/kextList.txt` in a text editor and looked for `Obtained from: Not Signed`
3. I removed all extensions (kexts) that wasn't signed from `/library/extensions` and `/system/library/extensions` and placed them in `~/Documents/Disabled Extensions/`
4. I then rebooted my computer but I still had the same problem.
5. I rebooted again in verbose mode by holding `Command V` on reboot
6. I noticed that this extension was loading `com.iospirit.driver.rbiokithelper`
7. I then went through `~/Desktop/kextList.txt` and looked for `Obtained from: Identified Developer` that also had `Loaded: Yes` set.
8. I found `com.iospirit.driver.rbiokithelper` was loaded. I googled it and found it was for Remote Buddy which I no longer used.
9. I moved `/Library/Extensions/RBIOKitHelper.kext` to `~/Documents/Disabled Extensions/` and rebooted.
10. Problem solved! 8-)

I hope this helps anyone else that has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this fixed it for me. https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/os-x-el-capitan-10-11-1-hanging-on-boot-fixed/

Comment: Your answer got my started on a solution. Kexts appeared to be the problem.